# Как загрузить данные по ссылке и распарсить ответ в JSON?

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc

У меня есть [ссылка, по которой сервер отдает JSON](http://api.steampowered.com/IPlayerService/GetOwnedGames/v0001/?key=5DDE73742302BAFF52D2B0D72DED476B&steamid=76561198226175440). Как мне получить содержимое по ссылке в виде строки и распарсить полученный JSON в дерево объектов?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

C использованием [Newtonsoft.Json](https://www.nuget.org/packages/newtonsoft.json/):

```
// сгенерировано студией через Edit/Paste Special/Paste JSON as Classes
public class Rootobject
{
    public Response response { get; set; }
}

public class Response
{
    public int game_count { get; set; }
    public Game[] games { get; set; }
}

public class Game
{
    public int appid { get; set; }
    public int playtime_forever { get; set; }
}

string url = "http://api.steampowered.com/IPlayerService/GetOwnedGames/v0001/?key=5DDE73742302BAFF52D2B0D72DED476B&steamid=76561198226175440";
var parsed = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Rootobject>(new WebClient().DownloadString(url));
```

Ручная работа с `HttpRequest` для скачивания строчки из интернета не нужна. По возможности постарайтесь избегать этого.

Comment: спасибо! всьо пошло

Comment: а как бить если вместо назви обекта есть ид - как тогда? http://steamcommunity.com/profiles/76561198038576078/inventory/json/570/2

Comment: @KASHMIR сделайте Edit/Paste Special/Paste JSON as Classes в студии - она сгенерит вам классы.

Answer (score 0):

```
HttpContent requestContent = Request.Content;
string jsonContent = requestContent.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
MYOBJECT contact = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MYOBJECT>(jsonContent);
```